# Publish App on windows 10 store with restricted namespace

Tags: namespaces, windows-store-apps, sms, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I try to publish an App on windows 10 store, but I can not pass test from Windows App Certification Kit:

> Restricted Namespace Error encountered: The restricted namespace test
>   Detected the following errors: Restricted Namespace found:
>   
>   Impact if not corrected: The Windows Store does not allow an
>   Application manifest to refer to restricted namespaces. How to fix it:
>   Removes restricted namespaces from the application manifest.

But I use a restricted namespace for use SMS functions:

Xmlns: r = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"

r: Capability Name = "cellularMessaging" />

How can made  this changes to publish ?

Comment: According to [special and restricted capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations), wen can see that Restricted capabilities are available for developers to use in their app, but require approval for store submission. All restricted capabilities must include the **rescap namespace** when you declare them in your app's package manifest differently than other capabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also add the rescap namespace IgnorableNamespaces in the Package.appxmanifest file as shown below.

```
<Package
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
    xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
    xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="cellularMessaging" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

When adding capabilities, keep them in the following order: 'Capability', 'rescap:Capability', then 'DeviceCapability', as there seems to be a problem when mixing them. ([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8efde534-f84a-48d7-9dd5-fec5043a894c/uwphow-to-use-a-restricted-capability-?forum=wpdevelop))

Note that the app certification test will probably continue to fail. You need to request permission to actually use these capabilities.

> Special and restricted capabilities are intended for very specific
>   scenarios. The use of these capabilities is highly restricted and
>   subject to additional Store onboarding policy and review. Follow the
>   steps below to request access to a restricted capability before
>   submitting your app to the store.
>
> 1. Determine if you are eligible to submit your app to the store with a
>      specific restricted capability by looking at the table below. If you
>      are not eligible, any requests you make will be denied.
> 2. If you are eligible visit the [Submitting an App](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=331509) support page.
> 3. Set the problem type to **App submission and certification** and the category type to **Submitting an app using a restricted capability**.
> 4. Include the capability you are requesting access to and include a reason for your request. If you do not provide all the information necessary, your
>      request will be denied. You may also be asked to provide more
>      information.
>
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities)

Comment: Thanks Bro, but I try to establish contact with Microsoft Support, but it is impossible :( People do not know how I can help me ...